# div appearing in random place

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my first website layout and the styling was going fine until trying to add a background colour to a div in the footer. It appears randomly in the page. I know it's probably to do with some other style i've used but I can't tell which as I don't have much experience. Any help as to why this is happening would be great.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body {
    background: #dce6f7;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #3f4042;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 150%;
    padding: 1%;
    text-indent: 2%;
    text-align: justify;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 150%;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

#logo {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}

#main-image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: solid 10px #2b477c;
}

a {
    color: #3a3b3d;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
    color: #476bb2;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#logo {
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
}

.main-nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 30px 20px 0 0;
}

.nav-backdrop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #2b477c; 
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
}

.intro-text h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.one-half-wrap {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align: center;
}

.section-header {
    font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.paragraph-text {
    margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.skill-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.one-third-padding {
    width: 29%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 2%;
    text-align: justify;
}

.one-third-padding img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.col-text {
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#footer-container {
    Width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Practice Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Practice.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<!--Top Nav Bar-->
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="header-inner">
            <img src="logo.png" id="logo">
                <nav class="main-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
    
<!--Main Image-->
    <div class="image wrapper">
        <img src="mainimg.png" id="main-image">
    </div>
    
    <div class="intro-text">
        <h2>Welcome To Our Website</h2>
    </div>
<!--Page columns-->
    <div class="one-half-wrap">
        <td>
            <h3 class="section-header">Heading Title Section</h3>
            <p class="paragraph-text">Lorem ipsum dolor amet cray truffaut gentrify ramps, chartreuse waistcoat brooklyn copper mug lo-fi taxidermy gluten-free drinking vinegar. Ugh stumptown banh mi hot chicken, keytar jianbing humblebrag. Kinfolk crucifix unicorn bicycle rights subway tile disrupt readymade fam vinyl kombucha man bun small batch hammock swag coloring.</p>
        </td>
    </div>
 <!--Column 2-->   
    <div class="one-half-wrap">
        <td>
            <h3 class="section-header">Heading Title Section</h3>
            <p class="paragraph-text">Lorem ipsum dolor amet cray truffaut gentrify ramps, chartreuse waistcoat brooklyn copper mug lo-fi taxidermy gluten-free drinking vinegar. Ugh stumptown banh mi hot chicken, keytar jianbing humblebrag. Kinfolk crucifix unicorn bicycle rights subway tile disrupt readymade fam vinyl kombucha man bun small batch hammock swag coloring.</p>
        </td>
    </div>
<!--End columns-->
    <div>
    <section class="one-third-padding">
        <h3 class="skill-title">Our Skills One</h3>
        <img src="columnimg1.png" class="col-img">
        <p class="col-text">Ugh stumptown banh mi hot chicken, keytar jianbing humblebrag. Kinfolk crucifix unicorn bicycle rights subway tile disrupt readymade fam vinyl kombucha man bun small batch hammock swag coloring book.</p>
    </section>
    
    <section class="one-third-padding">
        <h3 class="skill-title">Our Skills Two</h3>
        <img src="columnimg2.png" class="col-img">
        <p class="col-text">Ugh stumptown banh mi hot chicken, keytar jianbing humblebrag. Kinfolk crucifix unicorn bicycle rights subway tile disrupt readymade fam vinyl kombucha man bun small batch hammock swag coloring book.</p>
    </section>
    
    <section class="one-third-padding">
        <h3 class="skill-title">Our Skills Three</h3>
        <img src="columnimg3.png" class="col-img">
        <p class="col-text">Ugh stumptown banh mi hot chicken, keytar jianbing humblebrag. Kinfolk crucifix unicorn bicycle rights subway tile disrupt readymade fam vinyl kombucha man bun small batch hammock swag coloring book.</p>
    </section>
        </div>
    <div class="footer-wrapper">
        <footer>
            <div id="footer-container">
                <img src="logo.png" id="logo">
                <nav class="footer-nav">
                    <ul class="nav-text">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>   </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

</div> <!--End of wrapper-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Congrats on your first website code but why did you using "Div" tags everywhere in the page simply go with semantic (specified) tags.

Comment: Looks like you need to *clear your floats*, e.g: `.footer-wrapper {
    clear: both;
}` declaring this rule on the aforementioned element will clear floats on any *preceding* elements.

Comment: Look at here: https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/semantic-html/

Comment: I don't know why but I solved it with `margin-top: 800px;`. Add this to the footer class.

Comment: Hi @tpbafk rather not suggest a solution if you are not sure why it works, since you are most likely not aware of any "knock-on" effects that may become apparent as a result. This is a simple matter of *clearing floats*.

Comment: you can try  `display: inline-block;
width: 100%;`   it's most helpful in css.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fixed the position of the div element by adding postion as fixed and the color remains within that element.

```
#footer-container {
    Width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:pink;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}//it works good
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)